# How to animate expo-linear-gradient with reanimated?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I am using `react-native-reanimated` and want to animate the colors of my `expo-linear-gradient`. Unfortunately, nothing changes. I also created a [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.dev/@raider/reanimated-x-linear-gradient).

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import Animated, {
  interpolateColor,
  useAnimatedProps,
  useSharedValue,
  withTiming,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';

import { LinearGradient } from 'expo-linear-gradient';

const AnimatedLinearGradient = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(LinearGradient);

export default function App() {
  const colorsValue = useSharedValue(1); 

  const animatedProps = useAnimatedProps(() => {
    return {
      colors: [
        interpolateColor(colorsValue.value, [0, 1], ['#FFFFFF', '#000000']),
        interpolateColor(colorsValue.value, [0, 1], ['#FFFFFF', '#00ff00']),
      ],
    };
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <AnimatedLinearGradient
        animatedProps={animatedProps}
        style={{ height: 400, width: '100%' }}
      />
      <Button
        title="Change colors"
        onPress={() => (colorsValue.value = withTiming(0, { duration: 2000 }))}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Am I using animatedProps wrongly here? Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

unfortunately, I'm not sure you can do that. You're using correctly the `useAnimatedProps` hook, but usually it doesn't work for all properties.

If you want to achieve this type of animation, I highly recommend you to try the **LinearGradient** component from [@shopify/react-native-skia](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-skia/) package.

You can easily reuse the same logic, but with the Skia values:

```
 const colorsValue = useSharedValue(1); 
 const skiaFirstColor = useValue(0); 
 const skiaSecondColor = useValue(0);

 useSharedValueEffect(() => {
   skiaFirstColor.current = interpolateColor(colorsValue.value, [0, 1], ['#FFFFFF', '#000000']);
   skiaSecondColor.current = interpolateColor(colorsValue.value, [0, 1], ['#FFFFFF', '#00ff00']);
 }, colorsValue); // you can pass other shared values as extra parameters

 const colors = useComputedValue(() => {
  return [skiaFirstColor.current, skiaSecondColor.current]
 }, [skiaFirstColor, skiaSecondColor])

return (<... 
  <Canvas>
    <LinearGradient colors={colors} /> 
  </Canvas>
</>)
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thanks - that worked like a charm and is nicely animating on the UI thread :-). For the sake of completeness: it is also possible to do it with the normal React Native Animated library but that solution will run on the JS thread. Here is a good article about it: https://medium.com/@GroundControl/animating-gradients-in-react-native-8853dbd97d02

Comment: Can you share the solution bro, not manage somehow to make it work

Comment: Actually today I published a YouTube tutorial about this concept: here it is https://youtu.be/ZSPvvGU2LBg?si=BM0BpYoShr8nyHRJ :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it is not possible to do this with `expo-linear-gradient` because under the hood of this component on ios for example is [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer) and if you check reanimated docs for [useAnimatedProps](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/api/hooks/useAnimatedProps/) it says that:

> Only "native" properties of "native views" can be set via useAnimatedProps. The most common usecase for this hook is when we want to animate properties of some third-party native component, since most of the properties for the core React Native components are a part of the styles anyways (at least the properties for which it makes sense to be animated). You can use the following functions to animate properties that Reanimated don't support by default:

> addWhitelistedNativeProps() is used to animate properties that trigger layout recalculation, you can find them here.

> addWhitelistedUIProps() is used for properties that are updated directly on the UI thread, currently allowed props are listed here.

Also looks like it is not possible to do with SVG - https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/690

Maybe this example can help you to build your animation with SVG https://github.com/FullstackStation/react-native-svg-animated-linear-gradient